# ubuntu shares issue: always forced to start from the top level

Tags: ubuntu, network-shares, samba

After reorganizing my shares on ubuntu 8.10 they started working in strange way.

After just 10 sec of waiting in some folder I need to start from the top level of shares again. Also I can't just open any specific destination like server/video/xxx/yyy ... I need always open /server then go into /video etc...

Everything was fine before and I don't know how I make my shares so useless.

---

I have few windows computers (win7) and I'm surfing samba-shares under Ubuntu from THEM. Everything was perfect before reorganizing shares to the new hard-drive under Ubuntu. So I'm looking for any issue there.

Comment: Any chance that the shares refer to symbolic links? (I doubt it matters, but as you're writing about "reorganizing", I'm trying to imagine what could have happened while doing that.)

Comment: Reorganizing in this situation means: At first I changed hard-drive for my shared data. Then moved data to the new drive, then organized shares there.

Comment: So, the new drive is *only* used for the shares? Then: any chance that the new hard drive goes into some standby mode when not using it? (Still, I doubt it would matter...) Maybe it even somehow unmounts itself?

Comment: Torrent-software on that ubuntu machine works with this drive permanently. So I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a problem of a missing browser-master, required for the Windows computers.

See this article for explanations of the concepts: [Windows Browsing](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/windows/ntwsguide/ntwsnfinding.html).

If the Ubuntu computer is to be the network's master-browser, see [Forcing Samba to Be the Master](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/NetworkBrowsing.html#browse-force-master). The previous sections also contain explanations of the concepts involved.

If you want to force the Windows computers not to offer themselves as master-browser, set in
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Browser\Parameters`

```
"IsDomainMaster"="No"
"MaintainServerList"="No"
```

Comment: As I can understand - guys there suffer a problem when trying to see smb-shares in their local network through nautilus. But I'm surfing smb-shares with win7.

Comment: @pukipuki: So... are you seeing this problem from your Windows machine then?

Comment: @pukipuki: Could you please add more details to your problem description.

Comment: I'm done, re-described briefly.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this issue a few versions of Fedora as well, so it's something in GNOME itself. Creating a bookmark at the desired level will allow you to go straight there.

Comment: Not working in this case (